# How to apply code changes in source files to the Scala console in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using the Scala console to experiment with some code I have written in several source files. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15. When I make changes to the source it seems I have to restart the console for the changes to have an effect. Is there a shortcut? Or can I configure IDEA/the console to recompile and reload the files automatically?

Comment: I am not sure about the console. If you use terminal, try this:

sbt ~compile:compile